# Abrir página con javascript

Tags: javascript, html

¿Cómo va?
Tengo una , etoy intentando abrir una página desde `javascript` por medio del `botón.` La cosa es que se abre en una pestaña nueva, pero yo quiero que se abra en la misma pestaña.

**Botón:**

```
<input type="button" name="Certificados" value="Certificados" onclick="location.href='javascript:certificaciones()'" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
function certificaciones() {
    window.open('http://www.ejemplo.com.ar/');
}
```

¿Cómo lo soluciono?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intenta con este código para cambiar la URL estando en la misma página, es decir, sin abrir una nueva pestaña

```
function certificaciones() {
    window.open("http://www.ejemplo.com.ar/", "_self");        
}
```

Comment: Me lo ha abierto en una pestaña nueva también(?

Comment: código actualizado.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, ha servido :)

Comment: ¡Para servirles hermano, sigue adelante con el código! y recuerda seguir los lineamientos del sitio para colaborar con el orden de SOes, entre más orden exista, más fácil podrás ser el héroe de más usuarios que experimentan la misma situación, que tengas una buena semana :)